# Extending structure/document in a loop

Tags: javascript

Do you perhaps know if there is easy way to add more data to documents in a loop?
Document below presents what i desirable:

```
{
  _id: 'mydoc',
  _attachments: {
    'myattachment1.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob1
    },
    'myattachment2.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob2
    },
    'myattachment3.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob3
    },
  }
}
```

I would like to extend part "_attachments:" in a loop so that I am able to add new data. For instance there could be for loop running 3 times adding each attachment. How can this be easily achieved?

-----------Edited---------------
Expected result:

```
{
  _id: 'mydoc',
  _attachments: {
    'myattachment1.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob1
    },
    'myattachment2.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob2
    },
    'myattachment3.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob3
    },
    'myattachment4.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: blob4
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Your use of the word "document" and the look of the above suggests you're using MongoDB? Is that correct? And the goal is to add to the document in MongoDB, in a loop?

Comment: Do you want to add an element to _attachments? ex: myattachment4.txt? or a property to each element in the _attachments field?

Comment: Hi,  @T.J. Crowder: i use  pouchDB while building my small electron application;

Comment: @ospfranco: actually i would like to add additional element

Answer (score 1):

To insert a new field in the structure you have:

```js
const data = {
  _id: 'mydoc',
  _attachments: {
    'myattachment1.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: 'blob1'
    },
    'myattachment2.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: 'blob2'
    },
    'myattachment3.txt': {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: 'blob3'
    },
  }
}

Object
  .keys(data._attachments)
  .forEach(key => {
    data._attachments[key].myNewField = 'foo';
  });
  
console.log(data);
```

At least I think this is what you are after, as said in the comments, you might be using mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this can work.

Seems I need to get more familiar with the language itself.

```
    varNewAttachment = "XYZ.txt";
    varNewAttachmentValue = {
      content_type: 'text/plain',
      data: 'blob1'
    };

data._attachments[varNewAttachment] = varNewAttachmentValue ;
```